# AWS Apache server refuse to connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, terraform-provider-aws

- I created a new `Ubuntu T2 Micro` instance on `EC2`, created a new `Elastic IP` and selected `EIP used in: VPC`, associated the address to my new EC2 Ubuntu instance.

I now have a Private IP and a `Public/Elastic IP`. No Public DNS. My security group has `SSH port 22` and `HTTP port 80` and `HTTPS 443 open`. I use Terraform to create server

```
user_data = <<-EOF
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install apache2 -y
sudo systemctl start apache2
sudo bash -c "echo your very first web server > /var/www/html/index.html"
EOF
```

I can connect to the instance just fine through SSH using AWS console, but when I try to browse to the Public IP through the browser it says connection refused. I can't ping it either.

I use systemctl status to check the server, it's saying

```
├─apache2.service 
             │ ├─2108 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             │ ├─2111 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             │ └─2112 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I can ping `google.com` form the Server.

I'm out of ideas.
Get website connected from public IP

Comment: Name
 
Security group rule ID
 
Port range
 
Protocol
 
Source
 
Security groups
 
Description

– sgr-0f024024e1c75298f 80 TCP 0.0.0.0/0 allow_web  HTTP
– sgr-06db05df18ba1bf34 443 TCP 0.0.0.0/0 allow_web  HTTPS
– sgr-0784b8dffb3f2e749 22 TCP 0.0.0.0/0 allow_web  SSH

Answer (score 2):

Some things to be aware of:

- Using SSH from the AWS Console (EC2 Instance Connect) isn't a valid test, as that doesn't require your instance to have a public IP.
- Just having a public IP assigned to your instance doesn't automatically make it available on the Internet.
- If your security group only allows TCP ports 22, 80 and 443, then you would not be able to ping the server.

Some things to try:

- Verify that you have an Internet Gateway and that the route table for the subnet your EC2 instance is in has a route to the Internet.
- Check the NACL on the subnet your EC2 instance is in and make sure it is not blocking the traffic.
- Make sure there is nothing preventing you from accessing the server, such as a corporate firewall or proxy.
- Try connecting to Apache from the command line on the instance to verify Apache is really serving pages: `curl -v http://localhost` or even `curl -v http://PUBLIC_IP_OF_INSTANCE`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed automatically when I tried to get in the web by public IP the second day. I am not sure if this issue is due to AWS cloud infra need time to consume new public IP? Like noticing routing table or forwarding table, but luckily it passed.

I think AWS supporter should troubleshoot this kind of issue, I believe not only me met it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).